# Cocoapods not install error. Skipping pod install on xcode iPhone 14 Pro Max

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

My code is correct, with no error in my code, and was tested and run on an android simulator.

Until I install an Xcode Simulator, it keeps telling me about Cocoapods not installing so the plugins won't work and therefore the app won't run.

Can someone please help me?

```
macbook@Galaxy-A11 xylophone % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that
  responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation
for instructions.



CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Did you install cocoapods.

Comment: Yes, I did use:
sudo gem install cocoapods

And yet the installation failing...